# Realloc using extern

Tags: c, extern, realloc

Hi im trying to figure out how to use realloc. I have made a small test project that im trying to malloc for the creation of the first element in main, followed by adding a number to that location then reallocating the array to hold one more element.

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int i =0;
int *fileTest = (int*) malloc(sizeof(char * ));
int amtFiles=0;
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
parseInput(fileTest , amtFiles);
printf("%d", fileTest[1]);
}
}
```

parse.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stddef.h";
#include <stdlib.h>


extern int parseInput(int *fileTest,int amtFiles){
printf("enter number");
scanf("%d",amtFiles);
fileTest = realloc(fileTest, (amtFiles * sizeof(char *)));

}

makefile

CC = gcc
CC_FLAGS = -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall -w
FILES = main.c parse.c 
OUT_EXE = Test2

build: $(FILES)
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -o $(OUT_EXE) $(FILES) 

clean:
    rm -f *.o core *.exe *~ 

rebuild: clean build
```

Comment: C is pass by value. You should return the pointer value. Otherwise the original one is unchanged.

Comment: Does your code even compile? Why are you using `extern` in parse.c?

Comment: Why are you typecasting the malloc of something that is the size of a `char *` as an `int *` and then later referencing its content as an integer value?  That's very bad.

Comment: How did you compile the program?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Your code has many problems - so it won't compile. If you correct it then you  wll have undefined behavior. And even if that is corrected - then also your program does nothing meaningful. I guess now is the time for you to tell us what you want to do?

Comment: im new to c and trying to figure out my issues it compiles without realloc

Comment: without `realloc` means? How do you compile?

Comment: Your code will *not* compile if you have warnings enabled as errors.  Try something like `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` and compile again.  Your code has serious, fatal problems that the compiler will immediately see.

Comment: I added my make file and corrected the parse call

Answer (score 1):

C is pass by value. You should return the pointer value. Otherwise the original one is unchanged. So from `parseInput` return the pointer or pass address of the variable and change it accordingly (not shown in example).

While reallocating use another pointer variable other than the original one, in case of failure you don't lose reference to the old memory.

Don't print uninitialized value. (in `main()`).

Don't cast the return value of `malloc`.

When printing a pointer do this `printf("%p",(void*)fileTest[1]);`.

Also you should put the extern declaration in `main.c`. You have passed incorrect number of arguments to the `parseInput` function. The code didn' compile.

Then after correcting the input - if you try then you might get segmentation fault or some similar error.

I have tried demonstrating something over here. The naming can be much more better. I have tried to keep the general aspects of what you have tried. Multiple source file with `realloc` used and tested, working with pointers etc.

#### main.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "myheader.h"


    int main(void)
    {
        int *fileTest = NULL;
        int amtFiles;
        int weTried = 2;
        while(weTried --> 0){
            printf("%s\n", "Enter the array size.\n");
            if( scanf("%d",&amtFiles) != 1){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in input" );
                exit(1);
            }
            else if( amtFiles <= 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Enter positive integral value");
                exit(1);
            }
            fileTest = parseInput(fileTest, amtFiles);
            if( fileTest == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Realloc failed." );
                exit(1);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < amtFiles; i++){
                printf("[%d]\n",fileTest[i]);
            }
        }
        return 0;

    }
```

#### parse.c

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "myheader.h"

    int* parseInput(int *fileTest,int amtFiles)
    {
        if( amtFiles <= 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in number of inputs");
            exit(1);
        }
        int *t = realloc(fileTest, (amtFiles * sizeof * t));
        if( t == NULL ){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Execution exception");
            return NULL;
        }
        fileTest = t;
        for(int i = 0; i < amtFiles; i++){
            fileTest[i] = 2017+i;
        }
        return fileTest;
    }
```

#### myheader.h

```
    extern int* parseInput(int *,int );
```

Compiled and run

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.c parse.c
./a.out
```